# Dowloading apk file into internal storage

Tags: android, android-intent

IS there anyway to download apk files on website directly into internal memory. I am well aware of writing data into files and getting images using bitmap into internal memory but unsure about downloading apk files directly

Answer (score 1):

APK files are just files. There's no reason why you can't download and store them exactly the same as any other file.